# how to validate dhparams in apache <=2.4.6

Tags: firefox, lets-encrypt

How can I validate that I've properly setup my Apache 2.4.6 server with a custom 2048-bit (or 4096-bit) dhparams config?

Following the [weakdh.org sysadmin guide](https://weakdh.org/sysadmin.html), I created my own `dhparams.pem` file with `openssl dhparam -out dhparams.pem 2048`. The guide says to add this to the apache mod_ssl config with `SSLOpenSSLConfCmd DHParameters "{path to dhparams.pem}"`, but this is only valid for Apache >= v2.4.7. I'm using CentOS 7, which uses Apache v2.4.6.

According to [this server fault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/698093/invalid-command-sslopensslconfcmd-perhaps-misspelled-or-defined-by-a-module-n), the solution in Apache v2.4.6 is to append it to the certificate file. So I did a `cat /etc/pki/dhparam/dhparam.pem >> /etc/letsencrypt/live/openbuildinginstitute.org/cert.pem` (and also cat /etc/pki/dhparam/dhparam.pem >> /etc/letsencrypt/live/openbuildinginstitute.org/fullchain.pem` && restarted apache.

But how do I verify from the client-side (my browser) that this config is in effect?

This is especially an issue as we use Let's Encrypt, so we want to make sure our 90-day cert renewals include this step, and I want to be able to verify it from the browser.

I already tried downloading the certificate with firefox's "View Certificate" -> "Details" -> "Export...", and I confirmed that the "-----BEGIN DH PARAMETERS-----" was *absent* from the resulting file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the exact prime in use by using wireshark and listening on the connection.

1. Filter the connection with `ssl && ip.addr = <host ip>`
2. connect to the server with `openssl s_client -connect <ip or fqdn>:443 -servername <virtual host name> -tls1_2 -cipher DHE`. DHE is important because ECDHE uses a different scheme.
3. Check wireshark for the `ServerKeyExchange`. You get the key length in bytes and the prime. I didn't put a dhparams in, so you can see that apache2 uses the Oakley Group 2 prime ([RFC 2409](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2409#page-22)).
4. Compare with the prime in your DH file with `openssl dhparam -in /path/to/dhparam.pem -noout -text -check`.

[image: wireshark]

Answer (score 0):

[This SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/905557/openssl-display-dh-parameters) provides an `openssl` command that will output the ServerKeyExchange in hex, and from that you can calculate the bit size.

This is helpful, but I'd prefer a command that could extract relevant data from the hex encoding & just print the base-10 bit size.

Comment: Hi maltfield, this looks more lik1 a supplement to your question than like an answer?